# Is it possible to determine the distance of the person using webcam?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I was exploring the sample programs for Face Detection in javacv. Is there any possibility of finding distance of the person whose face is detected in the Live Feed??

Comment: In order to find out the depth, either you need a stereo vision, or moving objects to find the correspondence points between frames. If you Google "finding depth from monocular camera" you're going to see that there many articles regarding this matter.

Comment: Probably you can make some estimate by considering the scale of the box enclosing the face with respect to the focal properties of the camera.

Comment: Im trying to do something with the help of width of the box enclosing the face, but the value varies with cameras.. is there any common formula for determining the distance of a person in a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Start with your camera (say camera_frame.{width=320,height=240}. 
Set some positions manually with a measuring tape(!):

```
- box.area/frame.area ≈ 0,6 -> e.g.  30cm
- box.area/frame.area ≈ 0,3 -> e.g. 100cm
- box.area/frame.area ≈ 0,1 -> e.g. 300cm
```

Every caputred detection box can now be found with a simple linear interpolation.
For any input resolution, just resize frame to 320x240.

Comment: This can be useful for one camera but varies from camera to camera. In general you need to calculate or get somehow the Field Of View of the camera to convert pixels to distance. And for every camera is different.

Comment: Well, dear paoktsi, one way could be to find the ground plane homography though mapping given at least 4 points (real world<=> pixel coords).